Is it possible to use cross-check in this particular context in American English?
Here is my sentence:

Experts appeal to news watchers/readers to diligently cross-check facts that they read on unverified websites or hear in news programs that are politically biased .

What makes me unsure about the use of "cross-check" in this particular context:
What I have observed is that this verb is used in contexts where not cross checking facts could have serious consequences. E.g. a journalist not checking whether the facts they have gathered for their article are correct or not, cross-checking a copy against the original document to avoid falsification,etc. (As a side note, I know that journalists are supposed to do some fact-checking before the facts they have collected are presented in an article or in a news program but nowadays, most newspapers and news programs are politically biased and they distort facts in favor of politicians they support.
Context-wise, I'd say the verb fits perfectly but I am still unsure.

Can you differentiate between cross-checking and fact-checking?

I think cross-checking implies rechecking from another source. Although it's often used when 2 people check each other's work.

Just "diligently check facts" would do in the sentence though. Certainly you can't say "fact-check facts" and "cross-check facts" is unnecessary.

M-W says "to check (something, such as data or reports) from various angles or sources to determine validity or accuracy." (Also a specialized hockey term.) This would fit both with journalists and readers, right? If there's more about this that confuses you, please edit to explain more (not just say "this seems fine, but I'm unsure"; what are you unsure about?) and qualify for reopening.
